# MySQL left join query - getting data from three tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following tables in database:

Table `post`:

```
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| post_id       | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_content  | varchar(50000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_date     | datetime       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_summary  | varchar(1000)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post_title    | varchar(300)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_visitors | int(11)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| category_id   | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `user`:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_image    | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_name     | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_password | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_type     | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_username | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `comment`:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment_content | varchar(600) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_date    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_title   | varchar(300) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need a query that will return `post_title`, `post_summary`, `post_date`, `number_of_comments_for_this_post`, `user_name`, ordered by `number_of_comments_for_this_post` (descending order).

Basically I need data from all three tables. I know how to left join two tables and get some data. For example:

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.post_summary, p.post_date, u.user_name 
FROM post p LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id=u.user_id;
```

How to extend this query by joining third table (comment) and add one more field – 'number of posts comments' ordered by most commented posts first (desc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join is just a [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) operator. Relational algebra is just another query formalism. A table is a relation, operations on them produce other relations. You can use multiple operations to produce the resulting relation. MySQL [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) manual page suggests it too.

To compute some statistic over a set of rows, you need [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). In this case you need `COUNT`.

```
SELECT
    post_title,
    post_summary,
    post_date,
    COUNT(comment_id) AS comment_cnt,
    user.user_name
FROM
    post
    LEFT JOIN user USING(user_id)
    LEFT JOIN comment USING(post_id)
GROUP BY
    post_id
ORDER BY
    comment_cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
 SELECT 
  p.post_id,
  p.post_date,
  p.post_summary,
  p.post_title,
  u.user_name,
  COUNT(c.comment_id) AS number_of_post_comments 
FROM
  post p 
  LEFT JOIN COMMENT c 
    ON p.post_id = c.post_id 
  LEFT JOIN USER u 
    ON p.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY p.post_id  
ORDER BY number_of_post_comments  DESC
```

Comment: this query doesn't return valid result

Comment: I have put `post` table content, queries and results in textual file, You can see it here: http://ge.tt/71ld1cC1/v/0?c

Comment: thantks for the report.. i corrected my answer, I hope now it's working even if I can't test it.

Comment: @Wlad Probably you missed the [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) utility. It dumps the table contents in form of SQL queries. The dump is easy to import and experiment on. But [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is still better.

Comment: @StarsSky yes, its ok now, just add `desc` at the end. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Easy, just continue with the normal syntax

```
select p.post_title, p.post_summary, p.post_date, u.user_name 
from post p 
left join user u 
on p.user_id = u.user_id
left join comment c
on p.post_id = c.post_id
```

Besides a useful little helper:

If you have the situation that the column in both tables to join has the same name use USING()
to make your mysql jedi life easier!

```
select p.post_title, p.post_summary, p.post_date, u.user_name 
from post p 
left join user u 
USING(user_id)
left join comment c
USING(post_id)
```

Comment: Padawan, don't use USING(). On larger queries, it gets too confUSING. And there's no performance benefit.

Comment: Ofcourse this is no performance benefit but its not a disadvantage either. And its less code I get a headache by reading table affixes such as user u  and then u.x = c.y I dont think this is confusing at all, but this is a matter of taste! Large queries are hard to read anyway it does not matter if its USING() or ON statements. Formatting your query with  new line does half the work of making it readable...

Comment: @Steini you didn't include `number_of_posts` comments field in the result, and ordering by that field

Comment: Absolutely. Each to his own, but USING() is definitely for the Dark Side.

Comment: @Wlad, yes I missed that... however alot of people posted that now before me so they shall earn the rep they deserve and I dont really need to adjust that now anymore.

Comment: @Steini Can you edit your answer if you know exactly what is missing because none of the answers gives proper results. Once again, I need posts (title, summary, date), user name, and number of the comments for that post. That are fields in one record. So, I should have as many records in result as how many posts are in database.